# How to convert a cURL call into a Java URLConnection call

Tags: java, curl, trace

I have a cURL command:

```
curl -d '{"mobile_number":"09178005343", "pin":"1111"}' -H "Content:Type: application/json" -H "X-Gateway-Auth:authentication" -X POST https://localhost:9999/api/traces/%2f/login
```

I need to create an HTTP Request in Java API which will do the same thing. I don't have any idea regarding this. Thank you in advance for those who will take time to respond.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do it. Firstly, since you want to send a JSON object, you might want to use a JSON library, for example, Google's gson. But to make it easy you can just send the request as a `String`. Here is a sample code that sends your JSON to your URL.

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build(); 

try {

    HttpPost request = new HttpPost("https://localhost:9999/api/traces/%2f/login");
    StringEntity params =new StringEntity("{\"mobile_number\":\"09178005343\", \"pin\":\"1111\"");
    request.addHeader("content-type", "application/json");
    request.setEntity(params);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);

    //Do what you want with the response

}catch (Exception ex) {

    //If exception occurs handle it

} finally {
     //Close the connection 
}
```